# Is the Stack Overflow entry page (for none registered/signed-in users) meant to filter newcomers out?

Tags: discussion, design, user-experience, unregistered-users

I just opened SO in an incognito window (used the wrong window) and was surprised by what I saw, getting to the actual Q&A site we all know was not intuitive, I had to click on "For developers" (or scroll down instead), then NOT click on the first thing that popped up, "Try for free" (Private Q&A), but instead click on either the "open community" link or on the lower down "Browse questions" button.

Is this meant to make newcomers think if they want to use the site? (Assuming they don't immediately use the search or arrive via a search engine.)

I understand that SO offers a private Q&A, I even got a large company I've worked for to sign up to it, however, I don't think unregistered users will start with a private Q&A, I'm pretty sure frequent users will be those that push companies to sign up and they will send the sign-up link directly to the purchase people and also the "Find a job" button is weird there, since I assume the SO jobs will be used by users with reputation in SO, so why wouldn't the public Q&A be the first link under "For developers", as for an unregistered user, it is probably the only relevant link.

This doesn't really matter to me, as I don't usually see this page, however I found this puzzling enough to ask about.

For reference, at https://ux.stackexchange.com/ I see something that actually makes a lot of sense for new users.

Comment: yes, it is. It's horrible by design and won't be fixed

Comment: Yes, looks like the same question, I'm surprised the similar questions feature didn't find this. Maybe a new question will get new answers from SO product or does it not work like that?

Comment: @DannyVarod Maybe SO were ashamed and decided to hide it away from prying eyes :p

Comment: @Nick Hmm, I have a few jokes in mind about that, however, since I mostly like SO, I won't tell them.

Comment: @Nick There's still `https://stackoverflow.com/?questions` (https://stackoverflow.com/?questions - open in incognito)

Comment: @Zoe I meant ashamed of the dupe target, not Public Q&A :joy:

Comment: @Nick An attempt was made :P

Comment: @jonrsharpe funny edit